# How to fix Bundler::LockfileError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rbenv

I am having issues running rails test from within vim. When I issue the `:Rails test` from vim it returns

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb|72| in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)

Some terminal command outputs that might help answering

1. `which -a bundle`

   > /home/my_user_name/.rbenv/shims/bundle
2. `bundle env`

   ```
   Bundler       2.0.1
     Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
   Ruby          2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
     Full Path   /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby
     Config Dir  /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/etc
   RubyGems      3.0.2
     Gem Home    /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     Gem Path    /home/username/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     User Path   /home/username/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
     Bin Dir     /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin
   Tools         
     Git         2.17.1
     RVM         not installed
     rbenv       rbenv 1.0.0-21-g9fdce5d
     chruby      not installed
   ```

Comment: I had to recompile vim from source with ruby support.

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty hack would be to change the `BUNDLED_WITH` option in Gemfile.lock to `1.17.3`. This seems to be an issue with Bundler. You can check this link for more info:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6784

Answer (score 0):

I assume that vim was build against a different ruby than you are currently using in your terminal. Because of that, it will also use a different ruby when executing code from within it.

You can validate that assumption by issuing:

`:rubydo puts RUBY_VERSION`

within vim and see if that version matches the ruby you have in the terminal. I assume, that vim was build against the system ruby while you are using an rbenv based ruby in the terminal.

If the assumption holds true, you can either rebuild vim against your rbenv ruby or can briefly switch to the system ruby via rbenv and run a `gem install bundler` for it.

Comment: I get "Sorry, the command is not available in this version" for `:rubydo...`

Comment: I assume you are using the [Rails plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails). From the plugin documentation I gather that it should also be possible to start a rails console via `:Rails console`. Within it you should then be able to issue `puts RUBY_VERSION`

Comment: `:Rails console` returns "/user/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in 'require': ? cannot load such file -- bundler shell returned 1"

Comment: Well, regardless of the error there, you have your answer already. As the error is reported using the `/user/lib/ruby/2.5.0` which is not your rbenv ruby `/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1` you have a version mismatch. To quickly resolve the issue `gem install bundler` when having switched to your system ruby but that version mismatch will cause other problems along the line. As such, you should rebuild vim against your rbenv ruby.